# How to define custom coding rules in SonarQube 5.1.1?

Tags: java, sonarqube5.1

I have installed SonarQube 5.1.1 and got it running at my localhost. There is only one thing I can't do: creating my own custom coding rule (for example, I don't want to allow System.out.println() in my code).

I have watched the tutorial on the SonarQube homepage but it is for the older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI is only for XPATH and could not be used with a java rule.
To add a custom rule for regex pattern matching, new plugin jar has to be created.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

There are two ways to extend the coding rules.

1. Writing custom rules using Java via a SonarQube plugin.(for details
   click [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Writing+Custom+Rules+using+Java).)
2. Adding XPath rules directly through the SonarQube web interface.
   (for details click [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Custom+Rules+using+XPath+Expressions))

You have to write custom sonarqube plugin for creating custom coding standard and have to place the jar file in extensions/plugins and have to restart SonarQube.While define the custom rules you have to define the custom parameters.

For more detils, please find the SonarQube [guildlines](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java).

Comment: Solution 1 seems legit. I will give it a try.
Solution 2 in SonarQube 5.1 version, you won't see the xpath rule exists in Sonar way Quality Profile.

Comment: Yes, you are right Xpath is depricated for Java. its only supported by c,objective-c , flex, python and VB scripts